# Web Service Ajax Returning HTML

Tags: ajax, vb.net, web-services, streamreader

Hey all i am trying to figure out why i can not get any returned HTML from my web service.

This is my javascript that calls out to the WS:

```
function getTVGuide(whatsBeingSent) {
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    async : true,
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://192.168.9.7/Service.asmx/getTVGuideData",
            data: '',
            contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccessCallTVGuide,
        error: OnErrorCallTVGuide
    });      
}

    function OnSuccessCallTVGuide(response) {
    console.log(response.d);
}

function OnErrorCallTVGuide(response) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + response.status + " " + response.statusText);
}
```

And the WS is this:

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function getTVGuideData() As String
    Try
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("c:\tvlistings.html")
        Dim line As String = ""

        line = sr.ReadToEnd()
        sr.Close()
        Return "done"
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Return "err" 'Ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

That works just fine if i only return something like "DONE".

However, if i try returning **line** then it no longer works. Giving the error:

```
ERROR: 500 Internal Server Error
```

I've tried chanign the return values in AJAX to:

```
contentType: "application/html",
dataType: "html",
```

and also

```
contentType: "application/text",
dataType: "text",
```

But i still get the same error...

What could i be doing incorrect?

Comment: Anything out of the "ordinary" in your textfile?

Comment: @NoAlias Its just standard HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: 500 Internal Server Error means that there's some internal exception in service. You may be getting HTML contents due to CustomError ON and customError module returning a HTML page configured in IIS. CustomError module will change Content-type to text/HTML.

HTH,
Amit